# Save multiple photos from iPhone camera roll to dropbox

Tags: iphone, photos, dropbox, camera-roll

As you know, when you're in the camera roll on an iPhone you can select one or more photos from the "send" button and take various actions.  One such action I have is "Save to Dropbox", but this is only available until I select more than one photo.

[image]

Beyond that, I can click "Save to Files" and one of the options is "Dropbox"; however, it's grayed out/disabled -- regardless of whether one photo or multiple photos are selected before clicking "Save to Files".

[image]

So how do I save multiple files from the camera roll to Dropbox?  Why would it not be possible using the standard method?

Note: I know that I can go to the Dropbox app and select multiple files to upload from the camera roll.  This question is specifically about doing this procedure from the camera roll.

Comment: I think you can only upload multiple photos from the Dropbox app itself.

Answer (score 2):

This has always annoyed me, that Dropbox does not allow you to save to your Dropbox from within the photos.app. Grr...

And from time to time I (re-)discover how Dropbox wants you do do this:

1. Open Dropbox
2. Tap the "+" button labelled "Create"
3. Tap "Upload Photos"

...and you will be presented with your camera roll, and if you scroll up, the rest of the pictures on your iPhone. You can now select as many as you want.

I've often hated on the way Dropbox does this as it is intuitively backwards but if you can do better than me and remember this "trick" you should be good to go.